# Error en metodo onSuccess SDK Facebook android

Tags: android

Estoy probando el sdk de facebook en un fragmento y lo hice de la siguiente manera 
Este es mi fragmento:

```
            package com.dedicables.videos.dedicable.Views.Login;

            import android.content.Context;
            import android.content.Intent;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
            import android.view.LayoutInflater;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.view.ViewGroup;
            import android.widget.ImageView;
            import android.widget.TextView;

            import com.dedicables.videos.dedicable.R;
            import com.dedicables.videos.dedicable.Session.SessionManager;
            import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
            import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
            import com.facebook.FacebookException;
            import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
            import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
            import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
            import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;
            import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
            import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;

            import org.json.JSONObject;

            /**
             * Created by em645 on 2/7/2016.
             */
            public class LoginDefault extends Fragment {


                private TextView info;
                private LoginButton loginButton;
                private CallbackManager callbackManager;
                private ImageView photoFacebook;

                SessionManager manager = new SessionManager();

                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                }



                @Override
                public View onCreateView(
                        LayoutInflater inflater,
                        ViewGroup container,
                        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getContext());
                    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_default, container, false);

                    loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
                    //loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
                    // If using in a fragment
                    loginButton.setFragment(this);
                    // Other app specific specialization
                    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
                    // Callback registration
                    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                            info.setText(
                                    "User ID: "
                                            + loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId()
                                            + "\n" +
                                            "Auth Token: "
                                            + loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken()
                            );

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel() {
                            // App code
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                            // App code
                        }
                    });
                    return view;
                }

                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                }

            }
```

Al momento de iniciar la sesion me arroja el siguiente error:

```
07-03 14:43:44.908 10704-10704/com.dedicables.videos.dedicable E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                    Process: com.dedicables.videos.dedicable, PID: 10704
                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=129742, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.dedicables.videos.dedicable/com.dedicables.videos.dedicable.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3365)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3408)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                    at com.dedicables.videos.dedicable.Views.Login.LoginDefault$1.onSuccess(LoginDefault.java:122)
                    at com.dedicables.videos.dedicable.Views.Login.LoginDefault$1.onSuccess(LoginDefault.java:119)
```

Donde las ultimas dos lineas de este error me apuntan a:

```
             loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                            info.setText(
                                    "User ID: "
                                            + loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId()
                                            + "\n" +
                                            "Auth Token: "
                                            + loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken()
                            );

                        }
```

Lo curioso es que cuando vuelvo a abrir la aplicacion la sesion si esta iniciada por lo que falla al momento de mostrar los datos en el textView info.
Si pudieran ayudarme estaria muy agradecido. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Revisando tu código lo que veo que hace falta es:

```
info = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

Comment: Wow que incomodo... bueno... me ha pasado una de esas veces donde el error es muy pero muy tonto... Muchas gracias por ayudarme